# How to pass & in java jar parameters?

Tags: java, parameters, jar

When I use `"&"` as parameters, the command line treats & as beginning of new command but & is a part of my argument. For eg-  If I run `java -jar Runner.jar ABC&DEF`.

I want parameter value as `"ABC&DEF"` but I get error as below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at Runner.main(Runner.java:11)
```

'DEF' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: DEF is getting picked up by your terminal, try surrounding abc&def in quotes (“abc&def”)

Answer (score 5):

You could try quoting the argument with `''` or `""`.

Comment: Since OP's execution environment is Windows, quoting with `''` will not work.

Comment: Got it the first time, @saka1029